# Methods of Securely sending data/ authenticating across domains

Tags: php, ajax

Methods of Securely sending data/ authenticating across domains.

Summery of question (short and simple):

- I have multiple domains.
- I want to use one domain for authentication to all others.
- I know the theory behind it and how it works.
- I don't know how to do it.

Question:

- domaina.com = central doamin
- domainb.com = secondary domain
- domainc.com = secondary domain

Part A: Login

The user visiting domainb.com should be able to input their login details to the login form, hit login, and that information must securely be sent to domaina.com/login.php. It will then process, validate set a cookie on domaina.com and then resend a validate signal to domainb.com so domainb.com can also set a cookies and create a session. Once that is complete the will be redirected to a page on domainb.com

Part B: Check

I want to make it so, whenever a user visits domainb.com or domainc.com the system will check for a valid session, if its valid it will just proceed, if not it will contact domaina.com and check for a cookie set by the login process. If set, it will set a cookie in the new domain and log user in. If not set, redirect user to domainb.com or domainc.com login page.

I don’t know how to send the info between the domain, so I’m looking for sample code or any type of thing that will help me out on how to securely (without https) to send data between my sites without leaving opening for hackers to easily take it.

I don't have a preference in language, but i prefer php, js, html and am open to ajax requests if it is secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall: NOT FEASABLE.  Assuming you want to have a Single-Sign-On (SSO), you really want subdomains of the same domain.  You're probably going to wrap this in SSL-HTTP which is not going to let cookies of one domain be accessable from annother domain.  It does sound like you want to Proxy calls to the other domains, so this isn't that much of a pain if you pass a backend token to identify a session that will bypass main authentication

Comment: Can you explain how i can pass a backed token?

Comment: A randomly generated token that is never put on the page, but is an agreed method that allows the various servers agree on the identity of the end user.

Comment: so how will the page then identify that the user is the person that the token belongs to? - im sorry if that is a noob question, im just trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what your looking for.[Simple Single Sign-on with PHP](http://www.jasny.net/articles/simple-single-sign-on-for-php/)